# Получить два значения из одного input

Tags: input, форма

Необходимо уменьшить количество полей в форме, требуется из двух полей "Фамилия" и "имя" сделать одно "Фамилия Имя".
Но при это в базу заносятся два значения, как фамилия, так и имя.
Вот как мне получить два разных значения с одного input? Это похоже на облако тегов(меток) где через запятую указаны. Только тут надо через пробел разделить переменные.

Извините, забыл указать, что это все для сайта. Регистрация в интернет магазине. Язык PHP

Comment: Не указан язык программирования. На python я воспользовался бы input().split() для создания списка или кортежа.
И в целом более подробно нужно описать задачу - как вводятся значения.

Comment: Не делайте так. Есть двойные фамилии, есть двойные имена. Вы уверены, что вам не нужны такие пользователи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В php  можно использовать функцию explode().

Например, explode(' ', 'Петя Иванов') вернёт массив, нулевым элементом которого будет Петя, а первым - Иванов.

Comment: Можно немного подробнее пожалуйста? Как правильно мне указать $data['firstname'] = explode(" ", "$this->request->post['lastname']")[0];

Comment: Я бы так написал:  
$fio = trim( $_POST['lastname'] );  
$info = explode(' ',$fio);  
$firstname = isset( $info[0] ) ? $info[0]  : ' ';  
$lastname = isset( $info[1] ) ? $info[1]  : ' ';

Comment: Спасибо вам решение